# I cant'f find a solution for this. Invalid Hook call error on gatsby develop but it works fine when running gatsby build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm getting the following error and I can't figure it out what's wrong with it. Any help would be welcomed!

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

my code:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-grid-system'



const ProjectsList = () => {

  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query ProjectsQuery {
        allProjectsJson {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
              description
              image {
                src {
                  publicURL
                  childImageSharp {
                    sizes(sizes: "400px") {
                      src
                    }
                    resize {
                      src
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );


  const getProjectsItems = (data) => {

    const projectsItemsArray = [];

      data.allProjectsJson.edges.forEach(item =>
      projectsItemsArray.push(
      <Col md={6} key={item.node.id}>
        <div className="project-card">
          <div className="project-img-wrap">
            <img src={item.node.image.src.childImageSharp.sizes.src} alt="image" />
          </div>
          <div className="project-text-wrap">
            <span className="project-title">{item.node.title}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Col>)
    );
    console.log(data);
    return projectsItemsArray;
  }  

  return (
    <Container style={{padding: "0"}}>
      <Row>
      {getProjectsItems(data)}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );

}

export default ProjectsList;
```

Comment: Works in build but not in develop sounds like [this problem.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15315)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried some of the suggestions in there with no luck at all, will give another go to a couple I did not tried yet. Do you think it's something wrong on how i call the useStaticQuery on the code above?

Comment: If you did it wrong then it would not work when you build it either. When you run it in dev it probably ends up with several versions of react.

Comment: of course, fair point!